# How to avoid warnings after making the frame work and using it by others

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I done a framework and I am using it in the other application. Functionality is working as expected with my frame work and there is no errors at all. But while compile time I am getting some of the warnings printing in the console like **"Could not load the "colourpal_red_selected.png" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier"** .
Basically what ever the LOGS I am using in the frame work source code those are not printing in the console but warnings only showing.

Question:Is there any way to stop the warnings by using any of the settings by the xcode.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to solve the problem itself.

Recompile the framework after you checked that the source image in question *really* is included into the framework. You can do this by going to the project settings, then to *Build Phases*, then to *Copy Bundle Resources* and make sure the image is added there. If not, simply add it. If you have many targets in the project, make sure, you are really inspecting the **framework target**.